# Curious Binomial Coefficient Property

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Let $p = 3m + 1 $ be prime.

Let $x$ be the integer closest to $0$ (not necessarily positive) such that:
$$ x \equiv {2m \choose m}  \pmod p$$

Then, is it true that:
$$ 9 \mid p+1-x$$

For example, when $m=2$, $p=7$, then $x=-1$ and $9\mid 7+1-(-1)$

I've programmatically checked it for $p<35000$, so I'm pretty sure it's true. I don't see any obvious way to simplify the binomial coefficient nor any obvious properties that is has. I'd appreciate any help in understanding why this is the case and if there's some kind of simple underlying relationship here I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quasi-answer: Note that modulo $p$ your binomial coefficient equals

$$\frac{(3m)!}{m!^3}.$$

This is because $m$ has to be even, and the product of $(3m) (3m-1) \cdots (3m-(m-1)$ equals $m!$ modulo $p.$

Now the numerator of the above equals $-1$ mod p by Wilson's theorem, while the denominator is a cube (so its multiplicative inverse is also a cube). Now [Gauss's theorem on cubic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity) should be enough to finish the argument.

Comment: Thanks!! Gauss's Theorem is really close to what I want. Mixing my notation with the link's, I get that $p=3m+1=(x^2+27M^2)/4$ for some M. This implies that $p+1-x=(x^2-4x+4+27M^2)/4 = ((x-2)^2 + 27M^2)/4$, so it suffices to show that $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. This definitely seems like the right track, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here without digging into cubic reciprocity further (which at first glance seems like a black box).